# Advertisement on an ASP.NET Website

Tags: asp.net, ads, advertisement-server

I created a website for a friend of mine a while ago. He is now wanting to earn some money using advertisements. I do not have any experience with advertisement and there doesn't seem to be much out on the internet (perhaps I am not using correct keywords to search with :)) ... so my question is ... how do you serve adds on an ASP.NET website and make money doing that?

(I have however looked into google AdSense and had him sign-up for that. They will be reviewing the website soon and let us know if they find us worthy enough to use their service but that only cover's text adds he is looking for banner type advertisement)

If any of you have/are using any service to serve adds on your or client's website please let me know OR if there is an application out there that I can use to serve adds with etc .... Any help I can get from you guys will be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The best place to start is with Google AdSense so you have him on the right track. If approved, you'll end up with a bit of HTML to put on your site. You could put that in a usercontrol, but that's really not necessary.

Probably the next step up for ads is something like Commission Junction or the Google Affiliate Network. I've used ASP.NET and SQL Server to server up random ads from these companies but, again, that's not necessary. They just give you a bit of HTML.

You'll make the most money if you can find people to advertise directly with you. But that generally comes after a site is busy enough to make money using the methods described above. Either way, there's no special coding required unless you want to do something fancy with the way ads are scheduled.

Comment: AdWords is for targeting keywords to display ads along side search results and on affiliate sites via their AdSense subscription.  You PAY for AdWords, you get paid for AdSense.

Comment: You're absolutely right. A mistype on my part (now corrected).

Answer (score 3):

Google adwords are used to drive visitors to your site by targeting ads based on their search results.

AdSense is the program from google for displaying ads on your website, which in turn come with a CPC or CPM figure.

Answer (score 0):

Google **monetizing web site**.

Asp.net also has an [AdRotator](http://www.aspnet101.com/2007/06/using-the-adrotator-control/) control that may come in handy.